# Internet Explorer 11: ParseInt works with strings but not with array elements

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, parseint

I'm writing a simple javascript functions that should be backward compatible with Internet Explorer 11.
The script must simply split a string and get integer numbers.

```
temp = "2010/10/20".split("/");
temp[3] = "2010";
temp_string = "2010";

parseInt(temp[0], 10) // returns NaN
parseInt(temp[1], 10) // returns NaN
parseInt(temp[2], 10) // returns NaN
parseInt(temp[3], 10) // returns 2010
parseInt(temp_string, 10) // returns 2010
parseInt("2010", 10) // returns 2010
```

So, the problem is that ParseInt isn't able to parse array elements that are a result of split method (temp[0]), but it works when they are defined directly as strings (temp[3] and temp_string).
It's a weird behaviour indeed.
The script works normally with other browsers.

Comment: Also, can you replicate this issue by creating a working snippet using `<>` from the toolbar.

Comment: You are right. I edited the post ;)

Comment: It does work indeed. Please reproduce the problem in a SO snippet or JSFiddle.

Comment: What happens if you type `temp = String("2010/10/20").split("/");` ?

Comment: parseInt(temp[0]) is working with IE11 on my machine. Did you check if your IE is not in the compatibility mode?

Comment: I tested it on Browserstack since I don't have a "physical" pc, but my client test it on his pc and has the same bug...

Comment: ok! I found the solution on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30783955/strange-behaviour-with-spliting-a-string-in-javascript: it seems internet explorer adds "non ascii characters" when splitting the string, so it's unable to do the parseint conversion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange behaviour with spliting a string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30783955/strange-behaviour-with-spliting-a-string-in-javascript)